# Can't retrieve data posted from jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post

I have a form with radio buttons and checkboxes and want to retrieve which of them are checked. The form is submitted using jQuery and the information is stored in two variables (targets and diffs). These variables are then posted using $.ajax().

My problem: Firebug tells me that they have been posted, still I can't seem to retrieve them using $_POST. Actually, $_POST returns old data. I tried unset($_POST) and deleting my browser cache, nothing worked. What can I do?

Thank you so much for your help!

submit.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
alert('start');
    $('#right').on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
        var checkboxes = new Array();
        $('input[name=target]:checked').each(function(){
            checkboxes.push($(this).val());
        });
        var radio = $('input[name=diff]:radio:checked').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'targets': checkboxes, 'diffs': radio},
            success: function() {
                alert("success"); }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/submit.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['targets'])){
    $targets = $_POST['targets'];
    echo "targets set";
}

if(isset($_POST['diffs'])){
    $diffs = $_POST['diffs'];
    echo "diffs set";
}
?>

<div id="right">
    <div class="content">
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <input type="checkbox" name="target" value="Check1">Check1
            <input type="checkbox" name="target" value="Check2">Check2
            <input type="checkbox" name="target" value="Check3">Check3

            <input type="radio" name="diff" value="Radio1">Radio1
            <input type="radio" name="diff" value="Radio2">Radio2
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're submitting the form with ajax, but you're not capturing the returned data? What are you expecting the echo's to do ?

Comment: Also, you have syntax errors, the success function isn't closed, so the form probably submits the regular way.

Comment: I tried capturing the returned data using $_POST... How is it done correctly? - The echos are just for telling me if it worked. - The syntax error happened because I deleted something before posting it here, not an issue, fixed now. Also, #right does contain the form, so the form does submit. I can see the submitted values in firebug. I just can't retrieve them to be used in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#right form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var checkboxes = $.map($('input[name=target]:checked'), function(el,i){
            return el.value;
        });
        var radio = $('input[name=diff]:radio:checked').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {targets: checkboxes, diffs: radio}
        }).done(function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#content').html(data);
        }):
    });
});
```

Comment: Looking good! Just one more thing: This alerts me with the HTML-Code for the site I'd like to see. How do I output it in the browser instead of the alert box?

Comment: @eevaa - by using standard DOM manipulation methods in jQuery, like append(), prepend(), html() etc. See edited answer that would replace everything inside #content with the data returned.